# Is it possible to backup an Amazon RDS database to another service?

Tags: backup, replication, amazon-rds, rds

I moved my site's database to RDS a few months ago.  At the time, I finally decided I was ready to have a dedicated database server, and during the process of setting one up on EC2, I discovered RDS.  I've been really happy with it.

The problem is this:  While I understand that Amazon is running great backups of my database, and I'm excited about that, I don't feel good about having all my eggs in one basket.  Because RDS won't give you access to the binlog, I'm not sure how/if it's possible to back up elsewhere - I'd like to keep a backup on an entirely separate service, and I'd like it to be as up to date as possible.

It sounds like read replication to a server outside of AWS is out of the question (but correct me if I'm wrong there).  Do I have any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mainly depends on your database size and workload. If you don't need to have access to the binary logfiles and you have some smaller databases, you can simply run a mysqldump from a server elsewhere and store the SQL dump outside on your local harddrive, on a server harddrive or in Amazon S3. This won't give you permanent replication however, and the backup might take some time.